# hosting a flask webapp and CRON-activated Python script "together"

Tags: python, unix, cron, flask

I have a Python program that polls data from the web, saves it to a database, and sends out conditional alerts.

I also have a web application that will display some of this data to a website. The aforementioned Python polling program saves the data to be displayed to a Pickle object that is opened by the web app.

They will eventually be hosted on my VPS

I have the web app running on my local machine, but have not yet posted it to the web. The polling program is run via CRON once per minute.

Regarding the web app (built off of [Miguel Grinbergs awesome Flask mega tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)), Do I just call the "run.py" script in the root folder and send it to the background so that it is still active once I close my shell?

How do I ensure that the data displayed on the web is always the latest saved by the polling program? Will it automatically reload itself within the browser? Should these be further segregated?

The file structure is as follows

```
my_program_root_FOLDER
- run.py (for web_app)
- polling_program_code_FOLDER
-- file_run_via_CRON_for_polling
- web_app_FOLDER
-- static_FOLDER
--- Pickle_object (with data for web app)
```

Comment: Looks like you want to do something strange... Can't you have event driven system? What for is cron? Why you want to call "run.py" many times? (it is used only to run app). Why your flask app can't read data from database? Can't you just send pickled object with POST request to your flask app?

Answer (score 0):

The program you are running in `cron`, you can also run it in linux `screen` if you constantly want an updated result. In your local machine you are running your web app in the development server that comes with `Flask`. You must not use it in your vps. I recommend `uwsgi`+`nginx` .

Comment: I followed your advice and implemented uwsgi and nginx

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding the web app (built off of Miguel Grinbergs awesome Flask mega tutorial), Do I just call the "run.py" script in the root folder and send it to the background so that it is still active once I close my shell?

No, you would have to use something like `screen`, but the best approach is to run your application as a service, using some sort of service supervisor that makes sure your app gets automatically restartet when it crashes. [uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can do that for your, among other things. Other possibilities are [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/). Don't forget to disable Flask's debug mode if your app is exposed to the open internet.

> How do I ensure that the data displayed on the web is always the latest saved by the polling program? Will it automatically reload itself within the browser? Should these be further segregated?

If you did not implement some form of caching inside your app, templates will be rendered for each request, so it should always pick up the current data. If on the other hand you want the page inside the Browser to update automatically when new data arrives, without user interaction, you can implement that with Javascript and long polling. It's hard to give concrete advice here as it's not clear what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I got the app running with uwsgi and nginx. Is the uWSGI service supervisor you speak of the Emperor?